# How to render a component from an external function

Tags: typescript, react-native, components

react-native newbie here. I need to render a component from an external function.  I know I can make it using a state prop but I need to do it in this way cause I need it reusable is other classes etc.

I tried to return it as you can see below, but it does not work. When I click the button nothing happens.
Then, I tried to call the onPress function in all the way, like ()=>this.showPopup, this.showPopup and this.showPopup() (the last one is wrong at all).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import PopupComponent from './PopupComponent/PopupComponent'

export default class myClass extends Component{

showPopup = () =>{
   return(<PopupComponent isVisible={true}/>)
};

render(){
   return(
       <View>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.showPopup}> 
              <Text>PressButton</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>                
      </View>
   )
}
}
```

The component 'PopupComponent' works fine if I put it in the render function so I suppose there aren't problem in the component class.
As you'd guess, it's a modal that I want to make visible when I click on the PressButton. 
You guy have any ideas?

EDIT:
SOLVED! Basing on @milanika solution, I added in the component class the following code:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
      if (this.state.isVisibleState !== this.props.isVisible) {
          this.setState({isVisibleState: this.props.isVisible});
      }
   }
```

Where isVisibleState is a state prop of the component, and isVisible is what I pass from myClass.

Comment: EDIT: obviously there is the component's import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay 2 things:

If you want to render it after click simply made a state/prop for it and toggle it by function showPopup so f.e

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import PopupComponent from './PopupComponent/PopupComponent'

export default class myClass extends Component {
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { showPopup: false }
}

showPopup = () => {
   this.setState({showPopup: true})
};

render(){
   const { showPopup } = this.state;
   return(
       <View>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showPopup}>
              {showPopup && <PopupComponent isVisible={true}/> }
              <Text>PressButton</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>                
      </View>
   )
}
}
```

if you have isVisible prop in your PopupComponent you can pass showPopup state there as prop and put it on render method in this case directly without any logic on myClass Component but in this case on Popupcomponent return null if this.props.isVisible is falsy value.

Comment: This is what I first thought. There is a problem. The popup is showed just once with both methods you said ! It doesn't make any sense to me. In the component class I got a variable isVisible that receives a props from the main class. So I set it like this: isVisible=this.props.showPopup. And then I manage the modal setting the visibility with this.state.isVisible, and in the close button I've got a function which set the state of isVisible to false. It works fine, but just once! Indeed if I click again on PressButton in the main class nothing happens.

Comment: I printed the console.log of the variables I use in the main and in the component classes, and the situation is:
myClassState: false (at the beginning)
myClassState: true (after the click on PressButton)
ComponentState: true (it shows the modal)
ComponentState: false (when I click on close button)
myClassState: true (when I click the second time on PressButton
ComponentState: FALSE (<--- this is the problem! It does not change again)

Comment: I made it work man! Gonna post the solution in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Just returning the component won't help, you would have to use the returned piece of code somewhere in the render function like in the example below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import PopupComponent from './PopupComponent/PopupComponent'

export default class myClass extends Component{

constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { showPopup: false }
}

render(){
   return(
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setState({ showPopup: true }) }}>
                        <Text>PressButton</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {this.state.showPopup === true ? (<PopupComponent isVisible={true} />) : (null)}
                </View>
   )
}
}
```

You can test the code [here](https://snack.expo.io/SJse4LvZr)